# Combining two lists into one list where they share the same values and removing duplicates using list comprehensions

Tags: python, list, lambda, list-comprehension, typeerror

I am trying to combine two lists: 
One holds Square numbers. 
The other stores Pentagonal Numbers.

```
def pentaSquares():
    l = []
    n = 0
    squares = lambda x: [x*x for x in  range(n)]
    penta = lambda y: [y*(3*y-1)//2 for y in range(n)]
    while l.index < 4:
        l = [i for i in squares for j in penta if squares == penta]
        n = n+1
    return l
```

I must merge these lists using List Comprehensions where their values match until there are 4 elements in the list.

If somebody could point me in the right direction, that would be much appreciated.

I am currently getting this error: `TypeError: unorderable types: builtin_function_or_method() < int()`

Comment: Whoa can you step back a minute and let us have some sample input/output? Your code doesn't make much sense on its own and I hesitate to try and guess what it might mean if we fixed the mistakes.

Comment: `l.index` takes arguments

Comment: could you add a brief summary what is the input and what is the output? it seems you mixed up lambdas and list comprehension but when I look at your code I can't guess what do you mean...

Comment: @Rakesh_K insightful :P Unfortunately no argument you could pass to `l.index` makes sense, and none of them certainly satisfy "[loop] until there are 4 elements in the list." Similarly he's using `lambda x: [x*x for x in range(0)]` since he's defined `n` strangely. Oh yeah and iterating over function objects.... there's too much wrong here to throw out pithy observations without context.

Comment: There are no inputs. It is meant to go from 0 to n until the list has 4 values. The output is the error I wrote. If you can think of a way for me to hold these functions without lambda as the two lists to comprehend are not yet calculated I will gladly take it into consideration but it has to be in one program. The output I would like to get at the end is a list with the values of the two lists where the values are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def pentaSquares(n):
    squarlist=[x*x for x in range(n)]
    pentalist=[y * (3*y-1) // 2 for y in range(n)]
    l=[x for x in squarlist if x in pentalist]
    return l

>>> pentaSquares(10000)
[0, 1, 9801, 94109401]
```

**EDIT 1 O.P Satisfaction**

```
def pentaSquares(n):
    squarlist=[]
    pentalist=[]
    squares = lambda x:x*x
    penta = lambda y:y*(3*y-1)//2
    for i in range(n):
        squarlist.append(squares(i))
        pentalist.append(penta(i))
    l=[x for x in squarlist if x in pentalist]
    if l < 4:
        print('there are less than 4 values, input larger n')
    return l
```

Comment: @AdamSmith Hmmm just went through entire Wikipedia to find missing number, found it `0`

Comment: Thanks to everyone's help, this one solved my problem with cricket_007's input of `range(n)` and now it work. Thanks very much.

Comment: what? Why are we abstracting the first list comps into, and then out of, lambdas?

Comment: @AdamSmith Your answer is more efficient regardless of what OP wants. :)

Comment: @AdamSmith it's fine for me as long as it outputs what I need with List Comprehension which this satisfies.

Comment: @Jason well I edited the code to to eliminate entire `lamda` thingy

Answer (score 3):

Using a pair of generators should give you this answer without taking up all the memory in the world. This should work nicely (though perhaps take a very long time) for any resultant list size.

```
import itertools

squares = (x*x for x in itertools.count(0))
pentas = (y * (3*y-1) // 2 for y in itertools.count(0))

results = []

cur_s, cur_p = next(squares), next(pentas)
# prime the pump

while len(results) < 4:
    if cur_s == cur_p:
        results.append(cur_s)
        # success

    # advance the generator with the smaller current result
    if cur_s > cur_p:
        cur_p = next(pentas)
    else:
        cur_s = next(squares)
```

There's no reason to use list comprehensions for this task, but if you had to you should use the list -> set and set intersection approach in cricket_007's now-deleted answer

```
for n in range(itertools.count(0)):
    squares = [x * x for x in range(n)]
    pentas = [y * (3*y-1) // 2 for y in range(n)]
    result = set(squares).intersection(set(pentas))
    if len(result) >= 4:
        break
```

Comment: Yes the list method is very memory consuming , but where the other answer go.

Comment: I'm sorry but I need it to be List Comprehension.

Comment: The generator version runs quite fast, by the way, though, you should increment the generator when the values are equal

Comment: @cricket_007 it does increment when the values are equal -- there's no `elif` there. I'd originally advanced both generators on success, then used the `elif`, but then you miss the second solution (`1`)

Comment: Ah, oops. My version had an `elif`.

Comment: No, the output needs to be created by list comprehension. i.e. the comprehension of list squares and list pentas.

Comment: @Jason Who is imposing this requirement on you, and why?

Comment: @Jason there's no way to do that nicely, and I don't write bad code for free :)

Comment: (yes, you could use `itertools.product` and a double `for` loop in your list comp to slowly and painfully generate huge lists only to use probably zero if its elements, but you would NEVER EVER do this in production, it would be flagged IMMEDIATELY in code review, and you'd be an office anecdote for the next 5 years. "The code that can never forget," they'd say derisively of your memory consumption.)

Comment: I am trying to past coursework questions that our lecturer keeps every year and this one really confused me so I am actively trying to complete it within the questions guidelines

Comment: You could do it as a one-liner, too. It'd be just as bad

Comment: @Jason if it's a homework you can go for `list` comprehension code in below , but for professional it is a bad idea.